# JsonConvert DeserializeObject can't find int members

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have an odd situation, my other classes are deserializing properly but this one class with three int values doesn't deserialize properly. Using the trace writer setting I see that Json.Net reports that it can't find the members, but I'm not sure why.

Class:

```
public class BroadcastMemoryResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public int FreeMemory { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Malloc_Count")]
    public int MallocCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Free_Count")]
    public int FreeCount { get; set; }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "ID": 100,
  "Service": "BroadcastMemory",
  "FreeMemory: ": 50508,
  "Malloc_Count: ": 10050409,
  "Free_Count: ": 10049533,
  "Status": "Success"
}
```

Note that the `ID`, `Service` and `Status` fields are in the `BaseResponse` class and these successfully deserialized (`ID` is an int and that deserializes properly). I use `JsonProperties` to remove the underscore in the JSON when it's mapped to C#. The class and properties are all public and the getters/setters are public so not sure what the problem is..?

Test deserialization code:

```
ITraceWriter traceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter();
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TraceWriter = traceWriter };
string str = "{\"ID\":100,\"Service\":\"BroadcastMemory\",\"FreeMemory: \":50508,\"Malloc_Count: \":10050409,\"Free_Count: \":10049533,\"Status\":\"Success\"}";
var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BroadcastMemoryResponse>(str, settings);
```

Trace writer output:

```
2017-01-30T09:49:46.807 Info Started deserializing TcpClient.Core.Model.BroadcastMemoryResponse. Path 'ID', line 1, position 6.
2017-01-30T09:49:46.836 Verbose Could not find member 'FreeMemory: ' on TcpClient.Core.Model.BroadcastMemoryResponse. Path '['FreeMemory: ']', line 1, position 51.
2017-01-30T09:49:46.838 Verbose Could not find member 'Malloc_Count: ' on TcpClient.Core.Model.BroadcastMemoryResponse. Path '['Malloc_Count: ']', line 1, position 74.
2017-01-30T09:49:46.838 Verbose Could not find member 'Free_Count: ' on TcpClient.Core.Model.BroadcastMemoryResponse. Path '['Free_Count: ']', line 1, position 98.
2017-01-30T09:49:46.840 Info Finished deserializing TcpClient.Core.Model.BroadcastMemoryResponse. Path '', line 1, position 126.
2017-01-30T09:49:46.841 Verbose Deserialized JSON: 
{
  "ID": 100,
  "Service": "BroadcastMemory",
  "FreeMemory: ": 50508,
  "Malloc_Count: ": 10050409,
  "Free_Count: ": 10049533,
  "Status": "Success"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in your Json, you have malformed property names, (e.g. `"FreeMemory: "` instead of `"FreeMemory"`). This line:

```
"{ … \"FreeMemory: \":50508,\"Malloc_Count: \":10050409,\"Free_Count: \":10049533, … }"
```

Should be:

```
"{ … \"FreeMemory\":50508,\"Malloc_Count\":10050409,\"Free_Count\":10049533, … }"
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually have control over the messages, you can simply change the `JsonProperty` attributes:

```
[JsonProperty("FreeMemory: ")]
public int FreeMemory { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("Malloc_Count: ")]
public int MallocCount { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("Free_Count: ")]
public int FreeCount { get; set; }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.. I spent ages looking at this and didn't see that! I don't have control over the messages I'm receiving so must be a bug in the server. Adding `JsonProperty` attributes that match this bad JSON solved the issue.

Comment: @SimonM Glad I could help. I'd recommend bugging the original developer to fix the obvious typos in their code, but if that's not an option, yeah, you can just change the attributes in your code. I've updated my answer for completeness.